# Roman Numerals in ToC : Error in \settowidth

Tags: table-of-contents, width, tocloft, roman

I have a document in which I was trying to replace the arabic numerals of the chapters by Roman Numerals in the TOC. i.e

Instead of

```
Chapter 1  First chapter
Chapter 2  Second Chapter
```

I wanted

```
Chapter I:  First chapter
Chapter II: Second Chapter
```

I tried the following to get this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
%=================Content=======================
\newlength\mylength 
\newcommand*{\Romannumeral}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~\Romannumeral} 
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:} 
\settowidth{\mylength}{\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum\space} 
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength} 
%=============Set Chapter in Page==============
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}{\chaptername\space\Roman{chapter}}{20pt}{\uppercase}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
first chapter
\section{first section}
first section
\section{second section} 
second section
\subsection{first}
\chapter{Second}
second chapter
\section{first section}  
first section
 \end{document}
```

When I compile this get the following error

```
    ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   :
l.8 ...th}{\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum\space}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

When I manually set the width as

```
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{6em}
```

it compiles and shows the output correctly But due to variations in the size of chapter names it does not look great. So, How do I do this?

Comment: Unrelated: `tocloft` and `titlesec` ... no good idea.

Comment: You're overcomplicating things, in my point of view: Try `\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~} 
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}` The error is clearly inside of your `{\chaptername~\Romannumeral}` redefinition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~\Romannumeral}
```

is wrong, since `\Romannumeral` sees the `\numberline{1}` etc. statement, not the chapter number itself.

The whole thing is much easier, if `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}` is defined.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
%=================Content=======================
\newlength\mylength 
\newcommand*{\Romannumeral}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~} 
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:} 
\settowidth{\mylength}{\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum\space} 
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength} 
%=============Set Chapter in Page==============
\usepackage{titlesec} 

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}{\chaptername\space\Roman{chapter}}{20pt}{\uppercase}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
first chapter
\section{first section}
first section
\section{second section} 
second section
\subsection{first}
\chapter{Second}
second chapter
\section{first section}  
first section
 \end{document}
```